# Combobox y picker en Xamarin Forms no cargan al salir de la pagina y entrar de nuevo

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, combobox

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación con Xamarin Forms. En una página tengo un combobox y un picker. El combobox es autocompletable. Cuando inicio la app por primera vez todo funciona de bien, el combobox autocompleta las palabras y el picker muestra los elementos con normalidad. El problema que tengo es que cuando doy hacia atrás, es decir, salgo de esa página y vuelvo a entrar, el combobox ya no funciona y los elementos del picker están vacíos. 
El package que estoy usando es este: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/90324/announcing-combobox-and-floating-label-entry-for-ios-and-android
Los valores los obtengo desde un web service. El Json que obtengo nunca es nulo, está validado, por lo que los elementos si se guardan en el List string que necesitan el combobox y el picker para funcionar.